# Batch file locating duplicate patterns in filename then process

Tags: windows, batch-file

Ok, i've been working on a batch file for some time now, and im just stuck on the last bit.

What im trying to accomplish is to loop through a directory, create a variable which stores the filename of each file in the directory without the extension. Then for each file in the first loop, loop through a different directory and try to find any filename in the second loop that has the same name as stored in the variable, and then just output some simple text.

So for instance lets say in the first directory there is a filename called imafile-yehyeh.png, the variable will save imafile-yehyeh, then it will loop through all the files in the second directory, and output a message for each filename that has that pattern in it, so if a file in the second directory is called imafile-yehyeh_01.mp4 or imafile-yehyeh-newtitle.jpg, they would match the pattern and a message would output.

My script is looping and i am able to echo out all the variables, the files exist as i have created them exactly as shown above, but its not echoing out the `filename is set for deletion` line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. my code is as follows;

```
@echo off

set "parent_folder=C:\Users\Testing\script"

set "dupe_folder=DUPEFOLDER"
set "kill_folder=1 SCANNED\thumb"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%X in ("%parent_folder%\%dupe_folder%\*") do (
    set dupe_pattern=%%~nX

    for %%F in ("%parent_folder%\%kill_folder%\*") do (
        echo %%~nF | FIND "%dupe_pattern%" 1>NUL && (
            echo %%~F is set for deletion.
        )
    )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: You need to use delayed expansion with any environmental variables set inside a parenthesised code block. But in your case don't assign the FOR variable to an environmental variable. Just use the FOR variable directly with the FIND command.

Comment: @Squashman ... Is there any chance you could show me what you mean, I don't quite understand

Comment: Use the FOR variable with the find command: FIND "%%~nX"

Comment: @Squashman ohhh i see .. That has worked .. Thank you very much

Comment: `for %%F in ("%parent_folder%\%kill_folder%\%%~nX.*") do (` does not require use of `find` as the `for` handles the pattern search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from needlessly setting a variable, as already pointed out, you are also making the script inefficient. For every file in the `dupe_folder` you are `Echo`ing every file name in the `kill_folder` and piping that into a `Find` command looking for matches.

Here's a simpler way of doing it, *(it matches file names which begin with the same string followed by a dot, as opposed to any file name containing the string anywhere)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "parent_folder=C:\Users\Testing\script"
Set "dupe_folder=DUPEFOLDER"
Set "kill_folder=1 SCANNED\thumb"

CD /D "%parent_folder%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For %%A In ("%kill_folder%\*") Do If Exist "%dupe_folder%\%%~nA.*" (
    Echo %%A is set for deletion.)
```

Comment: interesting ... This will work better, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Squashman the answer was to remove the `set dupe_pattern....` line

and then change the FIND command to the following;

```
FIND "%%~nX"
```